# Combining these 4 SQL functions

Tags: sql, join

I have these 4 SQL features that look up the procedure of a patient and costs associated with it

Calculates procedures:

```
SELECT provider.Abbr, procedurelog.ClinicNum Clinic, procedurelog.ProcFee*(procedurelog.UnitQty+procedurelog.BaseUnits)- IFNULL(SUM(claimproc.WriteOff),0) Production, procedurelog.ProcNum, provider.ProvNum
FROM patient
INNER JOIN procedurelog ON patient.PatNum=procedurelog.PatNum AND procedurelog.ProcStatus='2' AND procedurelog.ProcDate >= '2021-06-10' AND procedurelog.ProcDate <= '2021-06-10'
LEFT JOIN claimproc ON procedurelog.ProcNum=claimproc.ProcNum AND claimproc.Status='7'
INNER JOIN provider ON procedurelog.ProvNum=provider.ProvNum AND provider.ProvNum IN (2,10,11)
INNER JOIN procedurecode ON procedurelog.CodeNum=procedurecode.CodeNum
GROUP BY procedurelog.ProcNum
```

Calculates Adjustments (if there is any)

```
SELECT provider.Abbr, adjustment.ClinicNum Clinic, adjustment.AdjAmt AdjAmt, adjustment.AdjNum, provider.ProvNum
FROM adjustment
INNER JOIN patient ON adjustment.PatNum=patient.PatNum
INNER JOIN definition ON adjustment.AdjType=definition.DefNum
INNER JOIN provider ON adjustment.ProvNum=provider.ProvNum AND provider.ProvNum IN (2,10,11)
WHERE adjustment.AdjDate >= '2021-06-10' AND adjustment.AdjDate <= '2021-06-10'
```

Calculates Writeoffs

```
SELECT provider.Abbr,claimproc.ClinicNum Clinic,- SUM(claimproc.WriteOff) WriteOff,claimproc.ClaimNum, claimproc.ClaimProcNum AS 'ProcNum', provider.ProvNum
FROM claimproc
LEFT JOIN patient ON claimproc.PatNum = patient.PatNum
LEFT JOIN provider ON provider.ProvNum = claimproc.ProvNum
LEFT JOIN insplan ON insplan.PlanNum = claimproc.PlanNum
LEFT JOIN carrier ON carrier.CarrierNum = insplan.CarrierNum
LEFT JOIN procedurelog ON procedurelog.ProcNum=claimproc.ProcNum
LEFT JOIN procedurecode ON procedurelog.CodeNum=procedurecode.CodeNum
WHERE claimproc.Status IN (1,4,0) AND claimproc.ProvNum IN (2,10,11) AND (claimproc.WriteOff > '.0001' OR claimproc.WriteOff < -.0001) AND claimproc.ProcDate >= '2021-06-10' AND claimproc.ProcDate <= '2021-06-10'
GROUP BY claimproc.ClaimProcNum
```

These queries were written separately because, on the backend, a server would do the calculations and get the total production. However, now I have to do it all in one query.

My issues is that I have no idea how to combine the:

- Production amount (from the procedures tables)
- Adjustment Amount (AdjAmt) from the Adjustments (if there is any, can be blank)
- Writeoffs (from the Writeoffs table)

Using this formula

```
Total Production = Production + Adjustments - Writeoffs
```

The provider number are the same since i am trying to calculate productions depending on the provider.

I think my problem is that i have gotten so lost in the "joins" that I dont know where to start to combine them and so the calculations.

How can I do it?

Comment: Removed conflucting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: I'd suggest to create custom function. What DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to join those queries without lost in the join jungle.

Using limited information you gave, this is the basic query using CTE.

```
WITH 
  production as (
  SELECT provider.Abbr, procedurelog.ClinicNum Clinic, procedurelog.ProcFee*(procedurelog.UnitQty+procedurelog.BaseUnits)- IFNULL(SUM(claimproc.WriteOff),0) Production, provider.ProvNum
  FROM patient
  INNER JOIN procedurelog ON patient.PatNum=procedurelog.PatNum AND procedurelog.ProcStatus='2' AND procedurelog.ProcDate >= '2021-06-10' AND procedurelog.ProcDate <= '2021-06-10'
  LEFT JOIN claimproc ON procedurelog.ProcNum=claimproc.ProcNum AND claimproc.Status='7'
  INNER JOIN provider ON procedurelog.ProvNum=provider.ProvNum AND provider.ProvNum IN (2,10,11)
  INNER JOIN procedurecode ON procedurelog.CodeNum=procedurecode.CodeNum
  GROUP BY provider.Abbr, procedurelog.ClinicNum, provider.ProvNum
  ),
  adjustment as (
    SELECT provider.Abbr, adjustment.ClinicNum Clinic, sum(adjustment.AdjAmt) AdjAmt, provider.ProvNum
    FROM patient
    INNER JOIN adjustment ON adjustment.PatNum=patient.PatNum
    INNER JOIN definition ON adjustment.AdjType=definition.DefNum
    INNER JOIN provider ON adjustment.ProvNum=provider.ProvNum AND provider.ProvNum IN (2,10,11)
    WHERE adjustment.AdjDate >= '2021-06-10' AND adjustment.AdjDate <= '2021-06-10'
    GROUP BY provider.Abbr, procedurelog.ClinicNum, provider.ProvNum
  ),
  writeoff as (
    SELECT provider.Abbr,claimproc.ClinicNum Clinic,- SUM(claimproc.WriteOff) WriteOff, provider.ProvNum
    FROM provider
    INNER JOIN claimproc ON provider.ProvNum = claimproc.ProvNum
    INNER JOIN patient ON claimproc.PatNum = patient.PatNum
    LEFT JOIN insplan ON insplan.PlanNum = claimproc.PlanNum
    LEFT JOIN carrier ON carrier.CarrierNum = insplan.CarrierNum
    LEFT JOIN procedurelog ON procedurelog.ProcNum=claimproc.ProcNum
    LEFT JOIN procedurecode ON procedurelog.CodeNum=procedurecode.CodeNum
    WHERE claimproc.Status IN (1,4,0) AND claimproc.ProvNum IN (2,10,11) AND (claimproc.WriteOff > '.0001' OR claimproc.WriteOff < -.0001) AND claimproc.ProcDate >= '2021-06-10' AND claimproc.ProcDate <= '2021-06-10'
    GROUP BY provider.Abbr,claimproc.ClinicNum, provider.ProvNum, procedurelog.ProcNum
  )
SELECT producttion.Abbr, production.ProvNum, production.ClinicNum, production.Production, adjustment.AdjAmt, writeoff.WriteOff
FROM production 
LEFT JOIN adjustment ON producttion.Abbr = adjustment.Abbr AND production.ClinicNum = adjustment.ClinicNum AND production.ProvNum = adjustment.ProvNum
LEFT JOIN writeoff ON producttion.Abbr = writeoff.Abbr AND production.ClinicNum = writeoff.ClinicNum AND production.ProvNum = writeoff.ProvNum
```

Note: not tested